# JavaFX on SBT for a Scala Project - object jfx is not a member of package org

Tags: java, scala, maven, javafx, dependencies

I am trying to import a openjfx into a Scala project.

The maven repo details are as follows:

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx
libraryDependencies += "org.openjfx" % "javafx" % "14" pomOnly()

My project build.sbt file looks like:

[image]

My driver class looks like:

[image]

But I get an error which says: object openjfx is not a member of package org

Could someone please guide me on how to use JavaFX with Scala?

Comment: Try using a lower version (Java 8) perhaps? Also, it'll probably be easier to use ScalaFX, although I don't know if it's possible for you to do so

Comment: Thanks, I am looking at both of these